# Why I get a Url with the default results of a webpage after I filter some options?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to analyze a table of football from a website using read_html().
To this I use the filters in the webpage to specify a season and then I copy the url. When I pass it to the read_html(), I get the same page but without the filters I used before copying the url.
How to solve this problem?
[here I use filter by position to defenders and then I copy the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jkva.jpg)

[When I use read_html() I get the table of the default page info with filter set to default "all positions"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2BLv.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the URL before and after you applied the filter to see that the URL is unaffected by the change, so no information about the filter is included in the URL.

It looks like you are expecting a PHP query string like you would get for a Google URL like https://www.google.com/search?q=my+search+string, but this page doesn't use PHP, it looks like it uses JavaScript to do the filtering.

I believe [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) provides the functionality to do what you want to do, but there'll be a bit of a learning curve. Good luck!